# How to get Individual name from Node value in Jena RDF Inf Model

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, jena-rules

I am facing a problem extracting the Individual's name from the Jena Graph (RDF Inference Model with Generic Rule Reasoner and OntSpec is RDFS_MEM_RDFS_INF ). It may be a simple case but I am not able to find proper tutorial online to get this done (new to jena rules). What is the proper api to call for in this case?

```
infStmts = pModel.listStatements().filterKeep( new Filter<Statement>() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Statement o) {                
            boolean ex = false;
            Property prop1 = pModel.getProperty(prefix + "hasPropertyP1");
            String predicateName  = o.asTriple().getPredicate().getLocalName();             
            if(predicateName.equalsIgnoreCase(prop1.getLocalName()) )                   
                ex = true;                
            return ex;

        }
    });

    Statement s = infStmts.next();
    Statement st = ResourceFactory.createStatement(s.getSubject(), s.getPredicate(), s.getObject());
    System.out.println(st.getSubject().toString() + "****" + pModel.getRDFNode(st.getSubject().asNode()).as(Individual.class));
```

```
Exception in thread "Thread-37" com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ConversionException: Cannot convert node 4e62503a:14b01762f42:-7eea to Individual
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.IndividualImpl$1.wrap(IndividualImpl.java:61)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:152)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:31)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.Polymorphic.asInternal(Polymorphic.java:62)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.as(EnhNode.java:107)
...
```

The Jena rules file has the following rule

```
[rule: ( :Subject1 :hasPropertyP2 :Object1) ->
       ( ?x rdf:type :Class1)
       ( ?x :hasPropertyP1 :Object2)]
```

I need the value of ?x in terms of individuals' names

Comment: What do you mean by the "Individual name"?  The IRI of a named individual?  A value of an rdfs:label property? Something else?

Comment: Yes, IRI of named Individual is what I want.

Comment: It is my understanding that the blank node (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_node) 4e62503a:14b01762f42:-7eea is holding the required set of individuals satisfying the rule and I would therefore like to retrieve the contained data which in this case is that of those individuals that have the hasPropertyP1 or that the jena rule is to be written such that individuals are retrieved similar to sparql queries

Comment: "the blank node 4e62503a:14b01762f42:-7eea is holding the required set of individuals satisfying the rule "  This doesn't make sense.  A blank node isn't a container, it's just an anonymous resource.  It's just like an IRI resource, except that it doesn't have an IRI.

Comment: If you found a solution to this problem in [your newer question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28070774/3747396), you should consider closing/deleting this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following line you're trying to get the the subject, then get a Node version of it, and then get an Individual version of it.

```
System.out.println(st.getSubject().toString() + "****" + pModel.getRDFNode(st.getSubject().asNode()).as(Individual.class));
```

You're doing this for the subject of every triple in the graph.  The documentation for [Individual](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/Individual.html) says:

> In order to be recognised as an individual, rather than a generic
>   resource, at least one rdf:type statement, referring to a known class,
>   must be present in the model.

The error message you're getting,

> Cannot convert node 4e62503a:14b01762f42:-7eea to Individual

indicates that somewhere in the graph, there's a triple whose subject is a blank node.  Apparently one of those blank nodes doesn't meet the criteria for being an Individual. You need to check whether the node can be an Individual before doing **as(Individual.class)**.  You can check first with **canAs(Individual.class)**.

However, you need to be aware that just because the rules file only has one rule does not mean that all the triples in the inference graph will have been generated by it.  There can be lots more triples in the inference graph.

A better way to do what you're trying to do would be to list the statements with the property that you care about using **Model.listStatements**, and then check whether the subject is a URI resource, and if is, then get it as a URI resource and extract its URI:

```java
Property p1 = model.createProperty(...)
StmtIterator stmts = model.listStatements(null,p1,null); 
while ( stmts.hasNext() ) {
  Statement stmt = stmts.next();
  RDFNode subject = stmt.getSubject();
  if ( subject.isURIResource() ) {
    System.out.println( "Subject URI is: "+ subject.asResource().getURI() );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it is this particular indivisual(blank node) that I want because it is the one that relates to the property(object/data property) I am querying for. Yes, all statements are being printed out here, but my code later pulls only this particular statement whose property is "hasPropertyP1" which is containing the node value instead of the iri. If I have written my rule to have directly reference the individual instead of variable ?x of a class, I am able to get the iri which is obvious but I want all the class elements so how to write the jena rule?

Comment: This node refers to those individuals of the class Class1 with predicate hasPropertyP1. Instead of the node, I want its constituents (individuals).This I cannot do in the java code as I want it to be generic and therfore need to write rule appropriately to get this data. I was not sure earlier and therefore asked for proper api to call but it looks like it is the proper rule to write so that the filter will have all statements containing respective class's (Class1) individuals rather than the class node itself. I suppose there are some constraints in rules to jena and rdf so how to do this?

Comment: @user3747396 Blank nodes *do not* have IRIs, that's what makes them blank.  I'm not sure what you mean that you're trying to get the IRI of a blank node.  I don't know what you mean by "constituents of a node".  Do you mean that you want the elements of a class?  I don't really know what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes, I want those iris(elements) of a class that satisfy the hasPropertyP1. If I change the rule `( ?x rdf:type :Class1) ( ?x hasPropertyP1 :Object2)` into `( :Individual1 :hasPropertyP1 :Object2)`, I can see the individual but if I have to write like this, I need to write for each corresponding Individual, If this is the only way to do things, the whole concept of classification using ontology itself is not of much use as I wanted to tune things by tuning ontology classes rather than each individual. I wanted `:Class1 :hasPropertyP1 :Object` and get satisfying individuals of Class1

Comment: @user3747396 What is it that you're actually trying to do?  Are you trying to ask, e.g., "what individuals have `o` as a value for property `p`?"  If you're trying to say "*if* an individual `s` has `o` as a value for property `p`, then `s` is a member of class `c`" you can do that with an OWL axiom `c subClassOf (p value o)`.  If you're trying to do that with a Jena rule, it would be like `[(?s p o) -> (?s rdf:type c)]`.

Comment: @user3747396 I don't find that question all that much clearer, to be honest.  It doesn't appear to be particularly minimal or complete.  If you just want to enumerate the individuals that have o as a value for property p, you can just call [listResourcesWithProperty(property,object)](http://goo.gl/1nZxjo).

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier I cannot do this at java code as the rules can be **composite** i.e a case may be listResourcesWithproperty (p1 and p2 and so on) .. .Also rules are added by users **dynamically** and therefore, I cannot write a generic code at the backend that will be able to handle both these difficulties. Do answer as you see fit and let me know of any shortcomings in my logical model

Comment: @user3747396 Then it sounds like you *not* trying to answer "what individuals have o as a value for property p?"  Rules don't provide answers;  they generate (or remove) triples from a graph.  That's all you can do with them.